# File Time sum not showing org mode Clock Table

Tags: emacs, org-mode, time-management

[image]

In org agenda clock table the file time is coming ** instead of sum of time in all task. How can I fix this?

Update:
This issue has been fixed in the latest build or org-mode and emacs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug AFAICS.

To fix it immediately you can fix function `org-clocktable-write-default` in your installation by replacing the line

```
(format (concat "| %s %s | %s%s"
```

with

```
(format (concat "| %s %s | %s%s%s"
```

Or you can wait for the next release of Org.

Comment: Do I have to do this on init.el or before build?

Comment: You could change the source file and rebuild Org.  You could also use the latest Org git versions.

Comment: I have the latest org, version from elpa

Comment: AFAICS the first version with the fix is 9.2.2. Can you check against your version?  The command is `M-x org-version` IIRC.